# exec command in bash loop for webscrapping

Tags: bash, shell-script, regular-expression, file-descriptors, exec

Here is a simple script which is curling https://unix.stackexchange.com/ and storing the result into an array, which is working fine.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/bash
[ -f pgtoscrap ] && { rm pgtoscrap; };
curl -o pgtoscrap https://unix.stackexchange.com/;
declare -a arr;
fileName="pgtoscrap";

exec 10<&0
exec < $fileName
let count=0
while read LINE; do
    arr[$count]=$LINE
    ((count++))
done
exec 0<10 10<&-
```

But, each time I run this script; I get some error for the wrong file descriptor.

```
./shcrap
./shcrap: line 14: 10: No such file or directory
```

I think I don't understand well how to use `exec` command in a loop correctly. Can someone explain?

**-- Update after implementing `mapfile` for Bash 4 it became much simpler --**

```
#!/usr/local/bin/bash
## Pass a parameter as e.g. ./linkscrapping.bash https://unix.stackexchange.com/
mapfile -t arr < <(curl -s $1); ## Doing exec stuff with process substitution
regex="<a[[:print:]]*<\/a>"; ELEMENTS=${#arr[@]}; firstline=0;
for((i=0;i<$ELEMENTS;i++)); do
    if [[ ${arr[${i}]} =~ $regex ]]; then
    [[ $firstline<1 ]] &&
        { echo ${BASH_REMATCH[0]} > scrapped; let firstline=$firstline+1; } ||
        { echo ${BASH_REMATCH[0]} >> scrapped; }
    fi
done
pg2scrap="scrapped"; mapfile -t arr2 < <(cat $pg2scrap);
regex="href=[\"\'][0-9a-zA-Z\:\/\.]+"; ELEMENTS2=${#arr2[@]}; line2=0
for ((i=0;i<$ELEMENTS2;i++)); do
    if [[ ${arr2[${i}]} =~ $regex ]]; then
    [[ $line2<1 ]] &&
        { echo ${BASH_REMATCH[0]#href=\"} > links; (( line2++ )); } ||
        { echo ${BASH_REMATCH[0]#href=\"} >> links; }
    fi
done; cat links;
```

Comment: Just for the record, you don't need that last `exec` at the end *at all*, unless you are *sourcing* the script or reusing this code *in a function*, because the file descriptor redirections don't effect the calling process from which the file descriptors are inherited, and because the file descriptors will be automatically closed when the shell process exits.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It surely has to do with how you close the file descriptor that you had opened earlier for stdin. Using the below should just be fine

```
exec 10<&-
```

When you do `0<10`, you instruct the shell to look for and to slurp in the contents of a file named `10` in your current directory which makes *no* sense in this context.

In `bash` you can also use an alternate form `exec 10>&-` which achieves the same purpose of closing the descriptor.

But that said, you don't need to use `exec` on random file descriptor and read your input, you can just read in your input with the process substitution technique in `bash` of form `< <()` as

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    arr["$count"]="$line"
    ((count++))
done< <(pgtoscrap)
```

Comment: In Bash 4 you could also use `readarray arr < pgtoscrap` instead of writing a loop. Or even `curl -s https://unix.stackexchange.com/ | readarray arr` to directly read the `curl` output into an array.

Comment: OP presumably intended to *restore FD `0`* by writing `exec 0<&10 10<&-`, and accidentally omitted the `&` ending up with `0<10`.

Answer (score 4):

`exec 10<&0` clones file descriptor number 0 to number 10, effectively saving the original so you can replace the file on fd 0 on the next line. To undo that, you'd need to reverse the numbers, to clone number 10 to number 0, `exec 0<&10` (and then close fd 10 with `exec 10<&-`).

On the other hand, `exec 0<10` without the ampersand is just a redirection with a filename `10`. Since you don't have such a file, you get an error.

---

That said, you don't need to use `exec` to temporarily set up a redirection for the while loop. Compound commands can take redirections too, like so:

```
while read LINE; do
    ...
done < "$filename"
```

If you want to read full lines as they are, without whitespace or backslashes affecting the data, you need to unset `IFS` for `read`, and use `read -r`. Also, if you're appending to an array, you don't need to manually keep up with the indexes, you can just use `+=` to append to the array directly:

```
arr=()   # declares it an array and clears it, not strictly necessary though
while IFS= read -r line; do
    arr+=("$line")
done < "$filename"
```

Or use `mapfile` (`readarray`) instead of a manual loop like @BlackJack mentions in comments:

```
mapfile -t arr < "$filename"
```

Or even without a temporary file at all:

```
#/bin/bash
mapfile -t arr < <(curl -s https://unix.stackexchange.com/)
```

(Without `-t`, `mapfile` leaves the line terminators in place.)

Comment: Now, I understand the FD, so it's almost the same as a closing `case`, `if` statement `esac`, `fi` so on and so forth. I was foolishly thinking for 10<&0 it should be 0&<01. I think it might be better to use single digit FD to avoid confusion? so `9<&0` will end with `0&<9` `9<&-`
Overall, using `mapfile -t arr` is far better approach I guess for Bash 4.

Comment: @RakibFiha, no, it'd still be `0<&9 9<&-`. It's just the numbers that get switched, not the other characters. The action that happens is the same regardless of which number is cloned to which. Also it doesn't matter if there's more than one digit, they're just numbers.